# Emacs - disable return and backspace keys

Tags: emacs

I have recently been feeling RSI setting in (I have had it before).

I have been paying attention to what effects my hands and the right hand bending out to press the backspace and return keys seem to be causing a lot of the problem.

I have defined "M-d" to backwards delete, which works fine, and I know about "C-m" entering a newline but I still keep involuntarily pressing the actual keys so I want to disable them in emacs.

I tried this:

```
(global-unset-key "\r")
```

But this breaks "C-m" as well
So I added this line:

```
(global-set-key "\C-m" 'newline)
```

But that restores the return key as well.

Please show me how to unbind just the return and backspace keys whilst maintaining the other bindings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting return and backspace to do nothing should work. That is, these two lines should suffice:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<return>") 'ignore)
(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>") 'ignore)
```

This will leave keystrokes like `C-m` operational.

Comment: Thanks this works great. It just came up after I clicked submit for my answer!

Comment: @event_jr Thanks, that's a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to work it out. Using this:

```
M-: (read-event "?") RET
```

You can find the event a key produces. So backspace was "backspace", and return was "return" (oops). You can then use that with the [return] format. So I added these lines to my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key [backspace] 'other-window)
(global-set-key [return] 'other-window)
```

Now if only I could get emacs my shortcuts to work with SO!